# Nth subset of a set

Tags: code-golf

### The task

Given the set

$$S = \left[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}\right]$$

and an integer

$$0 \leq N < 2^{|S|}$$

find the Nth subset.

### Input/Output

*N* is given as an unsigned integer on stdin. You must print the Nth subset in a format suitable for your language (this may include `[1,2,3]`,`{1,2,3}`,`[1, 2, 3]`,`1 2 3`,`1,2,3` etc. for as long as it is a human readable *text* format).

### A little bit about subsets

There is a relationship between subsets and numbers in base two. Each digit 
$$d_{i}$$ specifies whether the *i*th element of the set is within the subset.
For example *00000000* would be the empty set and *10000001* is the subset containing `[1,8]` (the last and first element). You get the Nth subset by converting the number into base 2 and then the subset includes all elements where $$d_{i} > 0$$. The 3rd subset (3 = 00000011) thus contains `[1,2]`. The rightmost digit is digit #0. It's ok to print `[2,1]`. The set does not have to be sorted.

**Addendums:**

Yes, the set is fixed to `1..8`. The set is not part of the input. Input is just *N*.

Yes, you may use alternate input forms.

All expected outputs for all *N*: https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fyNS02qIoP8soJd1CwSAg2kY32LPWPaoqs7jg/38A

Comment: Is the set specifically `1` to `8`, or is it any set?

Comment: Can we use a 1-indexed subset list instead?

Comment: It's specifically 1..8

Comment: @Giuseppe what do you mean?

Comment: Nth subset? In which order?

Comment: Could you include a few more test cases?

Comment: @mroman so `1` corresponds to the empty set rather than `1` and `2^8` corresponds to the full set rather than `2^8-1`.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody asked before: Would you be so kind to allow functions as submissions which take the input as argument and not force languages to use stdin (which some are not able to)? The question is about subsets and not fiddling with inputs.

Comment: @Giuseppe That's acceptable yes.

Comment: @Dennis https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fyNS02qIoP8soJd1CwSAg2kY32LPWPaoqs7jg/38A contains a list of all outputs.

Comment: @user202729 order is based on the base2 representation of N.

Comment: @BMO You may use alternate input forms, yes.

Comment: You don't need to tell everyone whether their solution is correct, you can restrict yourself to telling when it's not.

Comment: Since the set is limited to **1..8**, an output such as `"123"` would be unambiguous. Is it valid?

Comment: Can we use 0-indexed [0,7] instead of [1,8]?

Comment: @Arnauld By the looks of it, yes ("as long as it is a human readable *text* format").

Comment: Ah. See... that's why I prefer "fixed stdin/fixed stdout" because there's just going to be hundreds of questions for "can I use this shortcut" and "can I do this instead" questions all the time if you don't have fixed input/output.

Comment: You're just given `N` as an input.

Answer (score 17):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
BUT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98pNOS/kamZwsMd2xQObVU4ukfhcPujpjUKWSDiUeM2Bff/AA)

#### How it works

```
BUT  Main link. Argument: n

B    Binary; convert n to base 2.
 U   Upend; reverse the resulting array, so it starts with the LSB.
  T  Truth; find all 1-based indices of set bits.
```

Comment: But, but, BUT...?!

Comment: @Arnauld BUT everything is a lie! You think everything is Binary, eh? Well... that *Upended* is the Truth! So, nope, not everything is Binary. Welcome to the gray area!

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>52</s> 26 bytes

```r
which(intToBits(scan())>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMzlDIzOvJCTfKbOkWKM4OTFPQ1PTzkDzv5Gx8X8A)

Converts the input to its bits and returns the 1-based indices of where they are `TRUE`. That makes this a port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176463/67312).

Returns `integer(0)`, the empty list of integers, for input of `0`.

Comment: Although this answer contains no IFs, ANDs, or BUTs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda x:[i+1for i in range(8)if x>>i&1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjpT2zAtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNCMzNNocLOLlPNMPZ/QVFmXolCmkZmXkFpiYam5n8jI3MA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 33 bytes

```perl6
(1..*Zxx*.base(2).flip.comb).flat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfw1BPTyuqokJLLymxOFXDSFMvLSezQC85PzcJxEws@W/NxVWcWKmQpmGgaQ1lGcNZhkaWcLaRMVD8PwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n*[k]and n%2*[k]+f(n/2,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoMgAAXQuT3FX4igmEaaOpjoRUwHGkUN9mtQh54e7faWt/72caGJ0dWz/X46C2pfFxXT1r8tO1CYPzMn@TDaZ4WKbgkgJiJYDr00r1JV99saJu5IxPNA3kBsCQQkNa6oVDwB)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
ì2 Ôi ð
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=7DIg1Gkg8A==&input=ODg=)

```
ì2          :Convert to base-2 digit array
   Ô        :Reverse
    i       :Prepend null element
      ð     :0-based indices of truthy elements
```

---

```
¤¬²Ôð¥1
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pKyy1PClMQ==&input=ODg=)

```
¤           :Convert to base-2 string
 ¬          :Split
  ²         :Push 2
   Ô        :Reverse
    ð       :0-based indices of elements
     ¥1     :  Equal to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```hs
s n=[x|(x,d)<-zip[8,7..]$mapM(pure[0,1])[1..8]!!n,d>0]
```

Outputs the set in reversed order, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDoIwAAV3v@JBGCCUBhZlABZXnRxrhyY0QKSFtCUQ479X6/Zyd3mjsC85z95b6JYdn/QgfdYU72llNblQyhMl1nu6bkayklQ8YxWlNY8iTfqu5F6JSaPFsIDCSNGjbRoM0l0X7aR2FvsojTwhFCEMb0ifquiwbu7hzE0jgR2XHQp5jhg/E4f1Z6mFyjKwklLNfXX@Ag)

#### General version, 56 bytes

This will work for sets larger than \$\{i\}_{i=1}^8\$:

```hs
s n=[x|(x,d)<-zip[n,n-1..]$mapM(pure[0,1])[1..n]!!n,d>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCsMgFAXQX3mBDgkY0XbVLp37BeIg@Gilya2ohVDy7ybDWc471A8vS@@VYN22j5uIk5n/KTsIzFpKf1lDfo75V9gpof3kzoQfBoh4V76vIYEs5ZLQSFI9FQ6RrDH04vb4ojFa7Vpdbwc)

### Explanation

The term `mapM (pure [0,1]) [1..n]` generates the list (`n=4`) `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],..,[1,1,1,1]]` - ie. the binary representations of `[0..2^n-1]`. Indexing into it with `n` gives us the binary representation of `n`.

Now we can just `zip` it with the reversed numbers `[1..n]` and only keep the elements where the binary-digit is non-zero:

```hs
 [ x | (x,digit) <- zip [n,n-1,..1] binaryRepN, digit > 0 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 7 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1+&|2\:
```

**Example:**

First 10...

```
q)k)(1+&|2\:)@'!10
`long$()
,1
,2
1 2
,3
1 3
2 3
1 2 3
,4
1 4
```

**Explanation:**

```
1+&|2\: / the solution
    2\: / convert to base-2
   |    / reverse
  &     / indices where true
1+      / add 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```matlab
@(n)9-find(dec2bin(n,8)-48)
```

- reduced of 2 bytes thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- reduced of 2 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcndCkBAEEDhV5m7nSk2NspPynvIBXa35sKQxesvJXdf52zLOd0ueuhAax17FKpTz2LRusXMLChJRWlRUfTbAdxljSlLsBx2HORaTTgPZEpANaBGar/j3/RbqVdObMwf)

Comment: `@(n)9-find(dec2bin(n,8)-48)`

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
`fN↔ḋ
```

Takes input as command-line argument not on *stdin* ([I hope this is ok](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176460/nth-subset-of-a-set#comment424937_176460)), [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHN71HblIc7uv///28GAA)

### Explanation

```
`fN↔ḋ  -- example input: 6
    ḋ  -- convert to binary: [1,1,0]
   ↔   -- reverse: [0,1,1]
`      -- flip the arguments of
 fN    -- | filter the natural numbers by another list
       -- : [2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
↓⭆⮌↨Ｎ²×ιＩ⊕κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88T0chuATIS/dNLNAISi1LLSpO1XBKBBKeeQWlJX6luUmpRRqaOgpGmkAiJDM3tVgjU0fBObG4BKgiuSg1NzWvJDVFI1sTBKz//zcyNv6vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. If printing the answer horizontally without spaces is acceptable then the first character can be removed. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ       Input as a number
   ↨        Converted to base
     ²      Literal 2
  ⮌         Reversed
 ⭆          Map over bits and join
          κ Current index (0-indexed)
         ⊕  Incremented
        Ｉ   Cast to string
       ι    Current bit
      ×     Repeat string
↓           Print vertically
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

[+4 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYzBDoIwEAXvfMU70W4WlXrgAFa@hSAlNWSXUOLF@O21p8kcZt7TZ0rzEffzIvpacg7eShO9I/@U0UrtxsgGpjeGOFi53ZvIjormoIcVeLQDBA@4rpCZ8K2AWSXptlw3XcsOJSSqfvkP) if a separator is mandatory
[+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfT1lDT1i7PXiNPzdA@Wicz1kpdXVM7TSNP30gnU9tQE8j9n5ZfpJGnYKtgYK2Qp2CjYGgGpLW1NRWquRQUkvPzivNzUvVy8tOBpikANWpqctX@BwA) if this separator is a comma and a leading comma is allowed

```javascript
f=(n,i=1)=>n?(n&1?i:'')+f(n/2,i+1):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYw7DsIwEAV7n@JVxCvngykoII7PEiUxMrJ2kYNoopzduBpNMfOef/O@5Pj5dizrVkpwmtvoLLmJveaL9fHRNGSC5uHWRmOpagmSNcPh@gRjhL1XGkM4FLAI75K2PsmrrlBDInWWPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>13</strike> 10 bytes

```
-3 bytes thanks to Bubbler

1+I.@|.@#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9Q21PPoUbPQdnqvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRcXV2pyRr6CsZGCoZmKjkasdZqmgpqdQqaekanZfwA)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9Q21PPoUbPQdnqvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRcXV2pyRr6CsZGCoZmKjkasdZqmgpqdQqaekanZfwA).

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks! I thought I tried this - apparently not :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
{1 X+grep $_+>*%2,^8}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2lAhQju9KLVAQSVe205L1UgnzqL2vzVXcWKlQpqGSrymQlp@kYKBjoKxjoKhkaWOgpGxsfV/AA)

Alternative:

```perl6
{grep $_*2+>*%2,1..8}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 57 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(dotimes(i 7)(format(logbitp i x)"~a "(1+ i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxDoAgDAXQqzRMv3Fi0fMUUdMEhEAHJq@OvOGdSXudqE1fI0wkySEKBiMW03x1KB2Mu7QshlSeoFZJabD7hBz8RsrL3P3qBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
s n=[x+1|x<-[0..7],odd$div n$2^x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFEV3v@KGMECQRhx0KS6uOjliTZq0oUT6SmgVBv@9Wrebc05yjfRPPY4xelDbrVXzWXnd7Rg7iq1TKlfDG5TvH6uIVg6EFr0Dw6ylQss5eh3OjoKm4LEYPesNUpFCK6crirutT5he4RbmCyGHN26BRVUhw89kaf1Z4WHLEumbRGwOXw)

---

**37 bytes**

```hs
concat.(mapM(\i->[[],[i]])[8,7..1]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy7DoIwAEV3v@JCHNoAjSzqACyuOjmWDk2tQKSP0Br@3ipuN@ec3FGGl57nFNo@KWeVjIwY6W@kn6qOc1HySQjKz@WJsVpkGU1GThYtBgeGRcsH2qbBoOPF2ahtDFhHvegdtmILtzeQ3lQd/Dve43K12COMboVBUSDHz@Tb@jMSYCgFPzBmRaqPH/Wc5RBSpbz/Ag)

Test cases from nimi.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 47 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int y=0;y<8;)if((1&x>>y++)>0)Print(y);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYuxCsIwFEX3fsWjg7xHVdpFxLQBBzcHcXEQhxoSfaAppBUSSr89xi5OF845V/Ur1XPcq4E7W7MdJBhoom/kaDqHCUBoShHqrSA2iNXCSxmKgmRJJ5c0BhJTFFmWct2qJ8wfD2zhYD9v7dr7S6/PrX1oLJfVhgjGDODieNBHthp9ke@uOYkEDfp5/zK//cwUvw)

Looks similar to the Java solution now, although I came up with mine independently.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
¢Ô¬ðÍmÄ
```

[Test it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=otSs8M1txA==&input=MTU=)

---

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
¤Ôð1 mÄ
```

[Test it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pNTwMSBtxA==&input=MTM=)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3.6, 58 bytes

```
f=lambda n:[8-v for v,i in enumerate(f'{n:08b}')if int(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

```
Pick[r=Range@8,BitGet[#,r-1],1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/A/IDM5O7rINigxLz3VwULHKbPEPbUkWlmnSNcwVscwVu2/S350QFFmXkl0noKunUJadF5srI5CdZ6OgoGOgpGpaW3sfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
n->[x|x<-[1..8],bittest(n,x-1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y66oqbCRjfaUE/PIlYnKbOkJLW4RCNPp0LXUDP2f1p@kUYeUKGBjoKRqamOQkFRZh5QVkFJQdcOSKRp5Glqav4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 13 bytes

Prompts for N:

```
((8⍴2)⊤⎕)/⌽⍳8
```

[Try it online!  Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5raFg86t1ipPmoawlQRlP/Uc/eR72bLf4DJf@ncRkaAwA)

Explanation:

```
((8⍴2)⊤⎕) prompt for N and convert to binary

/⌽⍳8 generate a vector from 1 to 8, reverse and select integers according to 1s in binary
```

Returns subset in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 8 bytes

```
8roR@j!!
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/a9jZGz836IoP8ghS1Hx/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 77 bytes

```
select*from(select rownum r,value(p)from t,table(powermultiset(x))p)where:n=r
```

Test in SQL Plus

```
SQL> var n number
SQL> exec :n:=67;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> with t as (select ku$_vcnt(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) x from dual)
  2  select*from(select rownum r,value(p)from t,table(powermultiset(x))p)where:n=r
  3  /
        67
KU$_VCNT('1', '2', '7')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
â^mÉ┤\*─
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///worjcw52PpiyJ0Xo0peH/f3NjhWhDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHYtYAA)

### Explanation

```
â         Convert first input to binary list
 ^        Zip with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] (other input)
  mÉ      Map 2D array using the next 3 instuctions
    ┤     Pop from right of array
     \*   Swap top two elements and repeat array either 0 or 1 times
       ─  Flatten to 1D array
```

### Alternate output format

With a more flexible output format (that I personally think looks quite good) I can come up with a 6-byter:

```
â^É┤\*
```

Instead of mapping, I use the implicit for-each, and I skip the flattening. Output looks like this:

```
[1][2][][4][5][6][7][]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times{|a|n[a]>0&&p(-~a)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vJDM3tbi6JrEmLzox1s5ATa1AQ7cuUbO29r9CWrSFaSwXkDI0N4j9DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 45 bytes

```fs
let m x=Seq.where(fun y->x>>>y-1&&&1>0)[1..8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCFXocI2OLVQrzwjtShVI600T6FS167Czs6uUtdQTU3N0M5AM9pQT88i9n9afpFChUJmnkK0gZ6eoWmsQko@l0JBUWZeSVqegpKqo5KCBtAwzf8A)

I also implemented a generic/recursive function, but its pretty ugly and the byte count is a ***lot*** larger...

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 107 bytes

```fs
let rec g y i=
 if y>0 then seq{
  if y%2>0 then yield i
  yield!g(y/2)(i+1)
 }else Seq.empty
let f x=g x 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBCsIwFATQfU4xFgoJYm0LLlvwDC7Flf2pH9KkTbNoEM8eY8HVDI9h9HqanHUpGQrw9MSICO4EWCP2NcKLLFZa3gI7le0fI5MZwNn3dhhlPLdK8rFRAh8yK@FGS0XTHKL4vWts3YgNTdLO52SLe11VzeWBwQnMnm3QFkV5LSDzWKUv)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
bRSƶ0K
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KSj42DYD7///jYwA) or [verify all possible test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oqdHNz15J4VHbJAUle7//SUHBx7YZeP/X@Q8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
b         # Convert the (implicit) integer input to binary
          #  i.e. 22 → "10110"
 R        # Reverse it
          #  i.e. "10110" → "01101"
  S       # Convert it to a list of 0s and 1s
          #  i.e. "01101" → ["0","1","1","0","1"]
   ƶ      # Multiply each with its 1-indexed index
          #  i.e. ["0","1","1","0","1"] → [0,2,3,0,5]
    0K    # Remove all 0s (and output implicitly)
          #  i.e. [0,2,3,0,5] → [2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 58 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<8;)if((1&n>>i++)>0)System.out.print(i);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dU/BCoJAEL37FYOH2EWUCopoc/8gLx6rw7ZpjNkqugkhfrvNWocgmsMMM@/x3ptCdSosLrdRl6ptYa/Q9B4AGps1udIZJG4F6Cq8gGZ0B8MFnQaPWmuVRQ0JGIhhNKHs86qZSBjPBe42gmPO2GJmpMQg4HLO02drs3tUPWxUN8RkyMUwCqdWP84lqX1EJ8c75WGpJeL1cALF32G@TQB3y9WaBsm/UYBfj8DfHq0/BXdlIu18/9BLwz7YMD06jC8)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                        // Method with integer as parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;i<8;)         //  Loop `i` in the range [0,8):
    if((1&n>>i++)>0)        //   If 1 AND `n` bitwise right-shifted to `i` is larger than 0
                            //   (with `i` increased by 1 afterwards with `i++`)
      System.out.print(i);} //    Print `i+1`
```